# What is meaning of idiom "I COULDN'T BE BETTER"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I have seen people using this idioms while texting when i ask how are you they reply i couldn't be better so i want to know its meaning and which others idioms and words which i can use against this idiom ?

Comment: If they "couldn't feel better" then they must obviously feel exceptionally good.  If, on the other hand, they say "Well, I could feel better" then they are not feeling particularly good.

Comment: (The only place where "could"/"couldn't" gets a little messed up is with "I couldn't care less" and "I could care less" -- oddly, they both mean the same thing.)

Comment: It's not an idiom. It's just straight, literal English.

Comment: It is an idiom @Drew

Comment: It's a _set phrase_ that uses the literal meaning (thus, not an idiom) but uses it as an exaggeration; in other words, _hyperbole_

Comment: @BrianHitchcock No, it does not necessarily exaggerate - not any more than "*I feel perfect*" or "*I feel great*". It is a statement of feeling. It is a plain, logical statement about how the person feels. S?he *feels* that s?he could not be/feel better. S?he is feeling as good as s?he could possibly feel (she thinks). Whether what s?he feels corresponds with the facts is another question, and in that case, who's to say whether the feeling is accurate, whether, in fact, s?he could possibly feel better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'(I) Couldn't be better!' is an exuberant, upbeat reply to the question 'How are you?'
It's a British stock reply. I've heard it sometimes in older British movies from the 1960s-70s. The phrase crossed the Atlantic to New York City, where I worked in the 1980s and was popularized by radio political commentator Rush Limbaugh when his show broadcast from New York City in the 1990s, but the phrase hasn't spread much beyond Wall Street.

Comment: I probably hear it about once a week in the locker room of my gym in Rochester, MN.

Comment: Crossed the Atlantic to New York City? Where do you get that? Perhaps you happened to be in NYC in the 1980s. And perhaps you even thought that you brought it across the Atlantic with you. But my guess is that it was brought across the Atlantic as soon as English speakers crossed the Atlantic. It's certainly been on both sides of the Atlantic (whichever way it crossed the first time) for centuries.

Comment: An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+not+be+better%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccould+not+be+better%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20be%20better%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20be%20better%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), FWIW. "*The phrase hasn't spread much beyond Wall Street*." What makes you make this stuff up?

Comment: Drew 7--Guys like you wouldn't know how to go to the toilet unless you read a government document giving you directions.

Comment: Drew 7--There are no records at Ellis Island showing  the immigration of 'I couldn't be better' the United States. I checked when I was in NYC.